# Texture Altas for UIImage, about CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() performance

Tags: iphone, uiimage

My app has many graphics for the UI.
There is always 1-2 seconds lag when loading so many png files (with [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]).

So I am trying to pack them up into one big 2048*2048 image as a texture altas, like wt I did in rendering texture in OpenGL, to prevent the overhead of file I/O.
Then use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() to make the sub-images one by one.

The whole process is fast before the images are drawn.
From loading, making sub-images, to adding the UIImageView to my mainview.

But after adding those imageview, it need to wait for a large delay before the animation of my UI starts.
I used the Instrument Time Profiler and found that "png_do_read_transformations" should be the cause.

As I read the documentation, CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() created images only make reference to the data of the original image.
Does this cause the bad performance when I first drawn the image since transformation is needed?

Any approach can solve this problem?

p.s. the delay only appear when I first time add the image. no delay after the first appearance.